# Navbar control docking in split container panel1

Tags: c#, windows, controls

I am creating new dynamic navigation panel without using GUI. I have Split Container consist of panel1 and panel2. And also creating new navigation bar.

I try to do Navigation bar control object should be docking style as fill in split container panel1.

```
SplitContainerControl splitContainerControl1 = new SplitContainerControl();
splitContainerControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill

NavBarControl navBar = new NavBarControl();
this.Controls.Add(navBar);
navBar.BringToFront();
navBar.Dock =  DockStyle.Fill;
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution via different perspective and adapted to my code. here is the code if someone face this problem.

The idea is simple. just you need to add navbar in splitcontainercontrol panel property as follow;

```
splitContainerControl1.Panel1.Controls.Add(navBar);
splitContainerControl1.Panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(navBar, 0);
```